# What a reason that Filter in MS Access doesn't work the same on different computers

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013, adp

I have an old MS Access 2013 .adp project connected to SQL2019 database.
In project I have the forms based on queries from SQL Server. On this forms user can choose an employee ID from the combobox "EmpId" and get rows related to choosed employee .
The code is very simple :

```
Me.Filter = "[empid]=" & Me.EmpId
Me.FilterOn = True
```

The problem is that it works fine on 2 computers in the office and doesn't works on third one.
The problem is not in specific form, but on all forms that uses filters.

There is no error messages on that computer, but the filter simply doesn't applied. I see it on
the bottom panel of the form  1 of 8500 rows.

The 3 computers has the same OS WIndows 10 Hebrew and a project is in Hebrew too.
The security setting in all computers is the same "Allow all Macros".

What it can be ? Maybe some Access string settings ? Maybe Windows settings ?
Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: you might compare the Options area (File tab) and see if there is uniformity....can't think of anything else in terms of Access.  in terms of the PC's folder permissions be sure those are uniform

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't find the differences in options. Will try folder permissions.